# how to use images in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Here is my code.
I have an images folder inside the "src" folder and I want to use the images inside of my `components/Myapp.component.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import imageOne from '../img/cool-img.jpg';

function Myapp() {

  return (
    <div className="myapp">

      <h1>import image<h1>
      <img src={imageOne} alt="import-img" />

      <h1>relative-path image</h1>
      <img src="../img/cool-img.jpg" alt="relativepath-img" />

    </div>

  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

My problem is that the first import image works fine but the second relative path image does not work.

Comment: First, in the `<img>` you may have forgotten to add the image extension. 

Usually, I put images in the public folder: `your-project/public/img`, and then I reference them inside JSX like this: `<img src="/img/cool-img.jpg">`.

Comment: i added the extension and i does not work

Comment: the path you set is not relative to "your file", it's relative to "the page, once this is loaded in the browser". Put your images in a static assets directory (like `/public/images`), make your server serve those in the normal fashion (e.g. tell it that `public` is your static asset dir), and then point to that location using `src="/images/some/sub/path/your-image.ext"`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some common ways to import images in the `ReactJs` application. for such cases that images have separated server, it's so simple just call images like below:

```
<img src="https://images.cdn.com/sample-image.png" alt="sample-image" />
```

But if the images are for the application not for a show to the users, like images of UI design, there are two common ways:

1. Use [`copy-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin) and put all photos inside a folder then after build and serve, you should serve this folder and then you can call them from your link(eg: assume we run the project on the *localhost:3000*):

```
<img src="https://localhost:3000/sample-image.png" alt="sample-image" />
```

2. Just like your first trick, put all photos inside a folder and import them inside each component you need, then use it:

```
import sampleImage from '..[pathToAssets]/assets/imgs/sample-image';

~~~

<img src={sampleImage} alt="sample-image" />
```

I hope this answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because `<img src="../img/cool-img" alt="relativepath-img" />` image src is not resolved using [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) [file-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader), when you use `import` statement for a file, it will be checked first by Webpack and it will use the appropriate loader for the file type, in your case its an image so it will use file-loader, it will then handover the responsibility for it to handle the resolve of your file path,

If for example do a `console.log(imageOne)` it will `log` a path for your image, based on your public file path specified in your Webpack config file.

`<img src="../img/cool-img" alt="relativepath-img" />` on the other hand will be printed as is since it written inside JSX code and it will not resolve the real path for your public folder.

**So you should be using the first way (importing files) to resolve your files/images path.**